# Math and C++: How can I write a function where I add a number every 16 times?

Tags: c++, math

I have encountered a problem that may be solved easily if I could dominate Math. So If someone can point me out to the correct direction, I would gladly appreciate this contribution.

In a recipe, I want to add an X number, for example, number of lemons, every 16 cups. So when I have 5 cups, I would only use 1 lemon. When I have 17 cups, I would use 2 lemons. When I have 32 cups, I would then add a 3rd lemon, and like that every multiple of 16.

What could be the easiest way to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to dominate math for this:

```
int lemons = cups / 16 + 1; //the +1 there because apparently you want to start
                            //with one cup
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a direct relationship between lemons and cups, so you can just say:

```
lemons = ( cups / 16 ) + 1;
```

or if you like, you could also say:

```
lemons = ( cups >> 4 ) + 1;
```

which may be slightly faster and only works since (a) 16 is clearly and exact power of 2 and (b) if lemons and cups are integers. By the sound of it, it's unlikely that you need this kind of optimisation and the former is adequate and probably clearer.

Comment: Don't do the bit shift thing. It's much less readable, and any decent compiler will generate the same code anyway.

Comment: @interjay I agree about the readability. Not so sure that the compiler will generate the same code. Maybe if optimised, but g++ 4.7 certainly doesn't generate the same code unoptimised.

Comment: If you care about speed enough to make such micro-optimizations you will obviously compile with optimizations. I don't see how unoptimized compilation matters.